Clear indexeddb when auth session expires
I'd like to store sensitive information in IndexedDB for fast client-side persistant storage. However for me it's crucial that this data is only accessible to the currently signed in user.
Given that the session tokens expire at some known time (e.g., 1 week), is it possible to automatically delete all the data in IndexedDB when the session token expires?
That way the sensitive data does not persist beyond the auth session lifetime and therefore break a security boundary.
